# WP Elementor Plugin menu conflict

Tags: wordpress, plugins, menu, elementor

Trying to see if I can get some help with a sticky menu and Elementor conflict. After 7 hours of trouble shooting, I have determined that this is indeed the conflict because it shows on other pages and the admin theme customizer not using the Elementor plugin. I also turned off the plugin and the menu does work on index.php. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciate ... THANK YOU ALL!!!

http://centreforendodontics.apps-1and1.com/